# Linux command to list all files readable by others

Tags: linux, command-line

I need to list all files that are readable by public, in any directory.
For example, files with permission 777, 444, 604, etc.
How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It might be easier to build on top of your current partial solution and you show your research.

Comment: `find directory -type f -perm -o=r`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov that's an incomplete solution

Comment: user512658, what do you mean "_readable by public_"? Do you mean "_anyone other than root_" perhaps? Or "_anyone other than the current user_"? Or simply "_any file with "other" readable access_" (which isn't necessarily "_readable by public_"). Your permissions-based examples don't make sense (to me)

Answer (score 0):

Search for files which are readable by somebody (their owner, or their group, or anybody else)

```
find . -type f -perm /u=r,g=r,o=r
```

If you want find files readable for **others** in directory **/var**

```
~] find /var -type f  -perm /o=r -ls
   131113      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         2329 Nov  9 23:32 /var/spool/postfix/etc/localtime
   131150      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           66 Nov 18 13:45 /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf
   131084     16 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        12813 Nov  9 23:32 /var/spool/postfix/etc/services
   131151      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          251 Nov  9 23:32 /var/spool/postfix/etc/hosts
   131111      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          510 Nov  9 23:32 /var/spool/postfix/etc/nsswitch.conf
   131110      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            9 Nov  9 23:32 /var/spool/postfix/etc/host.conf
   132498    196 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       197624 Nov  9 23:24 /var/spool/postfix/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
   131169     52 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        51736 Feb  6  2019 /var/spool/postfix/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nisplus-2.24.so
   131125     20 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        18880 Feb  6  2019 /var/spool/postfix/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_hesiod-2.24.so
   131124     28 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        26960 May  1  2019 /var/spool/postfix/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.28.so
   131167     28 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        26952 Oct  2 14:47 /var/spool/postfix/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.31.so
.
.
.
```

- `ls` - list  current  file  in  ls  -dils format on standard output

Comment: It's only important that the files are readable by others so `u=r,g=r` and `ls` aren't needed. Your first find command will also include directories and links.

Comment: Nasir, what you don't understand on **Search for files which are readable by somebody (their owner, or their group, or anybody else)**? ``ls`` is for control purpose, you can delete this switch after visual control

Comment: This is any overly generous solution as you shouldn't consider user permissions. You should probably also get the OP to define "public" - for example, does this mean "_anyone other than root_" or perhaps "_anyone other than the current user_"?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to also account for the permissions of the directory. It's possible that the system has files that are world readable but the directory isn't readable or traversable by anyone other than the owner and/or group which would still make the files, in effect,  unreadable.

If that's doesn't matter and you know that everyone has permissions to read and traverse into the directory:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -perm -o=r
```

That will also recurse into subdirectories. If you only want the first layer of the directory:

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -o=r
```

You can adjust the number after `-maxdepth` for how far you want to traverse.

Comment: This is an incomplete solution as it excludes group members. You should probably also get the OP to define "public" - for example, does this mean "_anyone other than root_" or perhaps "_anyone other than the current user_"?

Comment: @roaima I understand that but as it none of that is clear, it's not possible to know what complete means considering as it's not possible for you, me, or anything else to account for every conceivable scenario that the person may want whether it's group members or anything else. The answer can always be edited later after that information is obtained.